# Doctrine PrePersist not working for its own entity

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have `Customer`, `Product`, `Budget` and `BudgetItem` entities. `Budget` is related as **@ORM\ManyToOne** to `Customer` and **@ORM\OneToMany** to `BudgetItem`. `BudgetItem` is related as **@ORM\ManyToOne** to `Product` and `Budget`.

Inside of `BudgetItem` there is a method for calculating the total price of `Products` previously selected, and then persisted into the `budget_itens` table. When updating the items, the code is executed and successfully persisted into the database again. The method is the following:

```
public function calculateTotalPrice()
{
    return $this->getProduct()->getPrice() * $this->getMeters();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function onPreEvents()
{
    $this->setPrice($this->calculateTotalPrice());
}
```

Now, I have inside of `Budget`:

```
/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function generateNextPaymentDate()
{
    if ($this->getStartsAt() !== null) {
        $date = new \DateTime($this->getStartsAt()->format('Y-m-d'));
        return $date->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $this->getCheckFor() . 'D'));
    }
}

/**
 * @return decimal
 */
public function calculateTotalBudgetPrice()
{
    $totalBudgetPrice = 0;

    foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $totalBudgetPrice += $item->getPrice();
    }

    return $totalBudgetPrice;
}

/**
 * @return decimal
 */
public function calculateInstallmentRatePrice()
{
    return $this->calculateTotalBudgetPrice() / $this->getInstallmentRate();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function onPreEvents()
{
    $this->setNextPaymentDate($this->generateNextPaymentDate());
    $this->setInstallmentRatePrice($this->calculateInstallmentRatePrice());
    $this->setTotalBudgetPrice($this->calculateTotalBudgetPrice());
}
```

None of these methods have their results persisted into the database after **editing** the `Budget`. If I understood well, it seems Doctrine2 does not update other related entities, but these fields belong to this entity. What else do I have to do?

**Edit**

The `BudgetController`, where I persist and flush.

```
<?php

namespace CDGBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use CDGBundle\Entity\Budget;
use CDGBundle\Form\BudgetType;

class BudgetController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lista todos os orçamentos
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('budget/index.html.twig', array(
            'budgets' => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CDGBundle:Budget')->findAll(),
            'title' => 'Lista de Orçamentos'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Adicionar um novo orçamento
     * 
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        $budget = new Budget();
        $form = $this->createForm(new BudgetType(), $budget);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($budget);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('budgets');
        }

        return $this->render('budget/add.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'title' => 'Novo Orçamento'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Exibe os detalhes do orçamento selecionado
     * 
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $budget = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CDGBundle:Budget')->find($id);

        return $this->render('budget/show.html.twig', array(
            'budget' => $budget,
            'title' => 'Dados do orçamento #' . $budget->getId()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Edita as informações do orçamento selecionado
     * 
     * @param integer $id
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function editAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $budget = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CDGBundle:Budget')->find($id);
        $form = $this->createForm(new BudgetType(), $budget);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($budget);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('budgets');
        }

        return $this->render('budget/edit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'title' => 'Editar orçamento #' . $budget->getId()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deleção de um orçamento
     * 
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function deleteAction($id)
    {
        $budget = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CDGBundle:Budget')->find($id);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($budget);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('budgets');
    }
}
```

My `Budget` class:

```
<?php

namespace CDGBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use CDGBundle\Entity\Customer;
use CDGBundle\Entity\BudgetItem;

/**
 * Budget
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CDGBundle\Entity\Repository\BudgetRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Budget
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="budgets")
     */
    private $customer;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BudgetItem", mappedBy="budget", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $items;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="installment_rate", type="integer")
     */
    private $installmentRate;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="check_for", type="integer")
     */
    private $checkFor;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="starts_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $startsAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deadline", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $deadline;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_approved", type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
     */
    private $isApproved;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="has_started", type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
     */
    private $hasStarted;

    /**
     * @var decimal
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="installment_rate_price", type="decimal", scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $installmentRatePrice;

    /**
     * @var decimal
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="total_budget_price", type="decimal", scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $totalBudgetPrice;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="next_payment_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $nextPaymentDate;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_paid", type="string", length=1)
     */
    private $isPaid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="obs", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $obs;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->isPaid = 'n';
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set address
     *
     * @param string $address
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * Set installmentRate
     *
     * @param integer $installmentRate
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setInstallmentRate($installmentRate)
    {
        $this->installmentRate = $installmentRate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get installmentRate
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getInstallmentRate()
    {
        return $this->installmentRate;
    }

    /**
     * Set checkFor
     *
     * @param integer $checkFor
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setCheckFor($checkFor)
    {
        $this->checkFor = $checkFor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get checkFor
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCheckFor()
    {
        return $this->checkFor;
    }

    /**
     * Set startsAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $startsAt
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setStartsAt($startsAt)
    {
        $this->startsAt = $startsAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get startsAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getStartsAt()
    {
        return $this->startsAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set deadline
     *
     * @param \DateTime $deadline
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setDeadline($deadline)
    {
        $this->deadline = $deadline;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get deadline
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDeadline()
    {
        return $this->deadline;
    }

    /**
     * Set isApproved
     *
     * @param string $isApproved
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setIsApproved($isApproved)
    {
        $this->isApproved = $isApproved;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isApproved
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIsApproved()
    {
        return $this->isApproved;
    }

    /**
     * Set hasStarted
     *
     * @param string $hasStarted
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setHasStarted($hasStarted)
    {
        $this->hasStarted = $hasStarted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get hasStarted
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHasStarted()
    {
        return $this->hasStarted;
    }

    /**
     * Set installmentRatePrice
     *
     * @param string $installmentRatePrice
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setInstallmentRatePrice($installmentRatePrice)
    {
        $this->installmentRatePrice = $installmentRatePrice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get installmentRatePrice
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInstallmentRatePrice()
    {
        return $this->installmentRatePrice;
    }

    /**
     * Set totalBudgetPrice
     *
     * @param string $totalBudgetPrice
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setTotalBudgetPrice($totalBudgetPrice)
    {
        $this->totalBudgetPrice = $totalBudgetPrice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get totalBudgetPrice
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTotalBudgetPrice()
    {
        return $this->totalBudgetPrice;
    }

    /**
     * Set nextPaymentDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $nextPaymentDate
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setNextPaymentDate($nextPaymentDate)
    {
        $this->nextPaymentDate = $nextPaymentDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nextPaymentDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getNextPaymentDate()
    {
        return $this->nextPaymentDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set isPaid
     *
     * @param string $isPaid
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setIsPaid($isPaid)
    {
        $this->isPaid = $isPaid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isPaid
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIsPaid()
    {
        return $this->isPaid;
    }

    /**
     * Set obs
     *
     * @param string $obs
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setObs($obs)
    {
        $this->obs = $obs;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get obs
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getObs()
    {
        return $this->obs;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set customer
     *
     * @param Customer $customer
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function setCustomer(Customer $customer = null)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer
     *
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }

    /**
     * Add item
     *
     * @param BudgetItem $item
     *
     * @return Budget
     */
    public function addItem(BudgetItem $item)
    {
        $item->setBudget($this);
        $this->items[] = $item;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove item
     *
     * @param BudgetItem $item
     */
    public function removeItem(BudgetItem $item)
    {
        $this->items->removeElement($item);
    }

    /**
     * Get items
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->items;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function generateNextPaymentDate()
    {
        if ($this->getStartsAt() !== null) {
            $date = new \DateTime($this->getStartsAt()->format('Y-m-d'));
            return $date->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $this->getCheckFor() . 'D'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return decimal
     */
    public function calculateTotalBudgetPrice()
    {
        $totalBudgetPrice = 0;

        foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
            $totalBudgetPrice += $item->getPrice();
        }

        return $totalBudgetPrice;
    }

    /**
     * @return decimal
     */
    public function calculateInstallmentRatePrice()
    {
        return $this->calculateTotalBudgetPrice() / $this->getInstallmentRate();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function onPreEvents()
    {
        $this->setNextPaymentDate($this->generateNextPaymentDate());
        $this->setInstallmentRatePrice($this->calculateInstallmentRatePrice());
        $this->setTotalBudgetPrice($this->calculateTotalBudgetPrice());
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

I have just realized that @ORM\PreUpdate is working but only for my `nextPaymentDate`. I have a `collection` in `Budget`, and inside of `ProductController` there is a method for gathering the Products information:

```
<?php

namespace CDGBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use CDGBundle\Entity\Product;
use CDGBundle\Form\ProductType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lista todos os materials
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', array(
            'products' => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CDGBundle:Product')->findAll(),
            'title' => 'Lista de Materiais'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Adicionar um novo material
     * 
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($product);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('products');
        }

        return $this->render('product/add.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'title' => 'Novo Material'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Exibe os detalhes do material selecionado
     * 
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Product
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CDGBundle:Product')->find($id);

        return $this->render('product/show.html.twig', array(
            'product' => $product,
            'title' => 'Dados do material #' . $product->getId()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Edita as informações do material selecionado
     * 
     * @param integer $id
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function editAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CDGBundle:Product')->find($id);
        $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->merge($product);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('products');
        }

        return $this->render('product/edit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'title' => 'Editar material #' . $product->getId() . ' - ' . $product->getName()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deleção de um material
     * 
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Product
     */
    public function deleteAction($id)
    {
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CDGBundle:Product')->find($id);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($product);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('products');
    }

    /**
     * Traz as informações do material selecionado na criação do orçamento.
     * 
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function getProductInfoAction(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->query->get('id');
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CDGBundle:Product')->find($id);

        if ($request->query->get('format') == 'json') {
            $data = array(
                'id' => $product->getId(),
                'name' => $product->getName(),
                'price' => $product->getPrice(),
                'meters' => $product->getMeters(),
                'description' => $product->getDescription(),
                'created_at' => $product->getCreatedAt()->format('d-m-Y H:i'),
            );

            return new JsonResponse($data, 200, array(
                'Content-type' => 'application/json'
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that there is a problem when editing it, because I experienced some errors, like if I change some Products info with after clicking edit, it is like there was no selected product at all.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events), specifically prePersist

> It should be noted that this event is only triggered on initial
>   persist of an entity (i.e. it does not trigger on future updates).

So you will also need to add a preUpdate listener.

Comment: I just saw it. The `calculateTotalPrice` method is executed after updating because it is actually a JavaScript function setting the total values. The method is actually useless. But still, adding an PreUpdate did not work. I added the annotation right under the PrePersist, or perhaps I need to create another method?

Comment: Do you have  @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks set on your entity? You can set both update/persist on a single method just fine so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes I do, since I created it.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you're doing. I've even tested a similar type method locally and it works on both create and update of the entity.

Comment: Please, could you take a look at my project in my Github to see if I am doing something wrong? https://github.com/mfgabriel92/cdg/blob/master/src/CDGBundle/Entity/Budget.php

Comment: It looks fine, I would suggest putting a debug print / exit inside Budget->onPreEvents to see if it is actually firing. Also I see you actually don't have preUpdate set on Budget->onPreEvents but I assume you haven't commited that to GitHub,

Comment: Also can you post your code where you're persisting and flushing the entity please.

Comment: I have updated it. I made some tests yesterday by echoing the returned value from each method, and even inside of onPreEvents, the returned values were correct. It seems it simply does not persist into the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93432/discussion-between-mfgabriel92-and-richard).